# How to change the black color in Android dialogs or drawer menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

In Android, when we show something like alert dialog, progress dialog, open drawer and etc, it seems we have a transparent black layer on the screen, then a kind of dialog, like this pic:

my goal is changing the transparent black layer, not background of dialog, see this picture:

[image]

How to change the color of this transparent black layer to something like red or any color? For example in XML or by code in java

this is my code for MyExitDialog class

```
public class MyExitDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener
{
    DatabaseHandler userDB;

    public Activity c;
    public Dialog d;
    public Button yes, no;

    public MyExitDialog(Activity a)
    {
        super(a);
        this.c = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.mydialog);
        yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_exit_yes);
        no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_exit_no);
        yes.setOnClickListener(this);
        no.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.id_exit_yes:
                //c.finish();
                DrawerActivity.userDB=new DatabaseHandler(MyExitDialog.this.getContext());
                DrawerActivity.userDB.open();
                DrawerActivity.userDB.logOut();
                DrawerActivity.userDB.close();
                DrawerActivity.changeDrawerItems("logout");
                break;
            case R.id.id_exit_no:
                dismiss();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        dismiss();

    }
}
```

and this is how I use that:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment myFragment = null;

    View myView;
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/BYekan.ttf");

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_register) {


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_change) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_login) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_factors) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        MyExitDialog myDialog = new MyExitDialog(DrawerActivity.this);
        myDialog.show();
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is this `background:@color/newbg`?

Comment: @UmarZaii it is just a hint

Comment: Include your dialog code in the post

Comment: It seems that you call your dialog from an activity. Is that right? If it is can you put the code where you call the dialog as well?

Comment: @UmarZaii yes,you right.I update my code again

Comment: I already update my code. There is another alternative and cleaner code. If you want that I can show you.

Comment: I have included all the alternatives to set the custom style for your dialog. Feel free to ask me if it didn't work. Accept the answer if it did ;)

Comment: @UmarZaii thanks, your code is working, but your code change the white background of dialog, not the transparent black!!

Comment: Done, I have updated my code. Please see it again. Can't stop laughing. That picture XD

Comment: @UmarZaii thanks. sorry for my bad english and my bad explains ;) the last code you wrote, change black background of drawer only, but what about black background of MyExitDialog !?

Comment: Updated my code again. Sorry again. truly. I hope this time it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you AlertDialog, you can set custom theme as the second parameter like this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.CustomDialog);
```

And in style.xml set a customDialog style

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Lastly, you can set your custom colour in colors.xml

```
<resources>
    <item name="blue" type="color">#FF33B5E5</item>
    <item name="purple" type="color">#FFAA66CC</item>
    <item name="green" type="color">#FF99CC00</item>
    <item name="orange" type="color">#FFFFBB33</item>
    <item name="red" type="color">#FFFF4444</item>
    <item name="darkblue" type="color">#FF0099CC</item>
    <item name="darkpurple" type="color">#FF9933CC</item>
    <item name="darkgreen" type="color">#FF669900</item>
    <item name="darkorange" type="color">#FFFF8800</item>
    <item name="darkred" type="color">#FFCC0000</item>
</resources>
```

There is plenty of colors to choose from.

**UPDATE:**

Try change from

```
public MyExitDialog(Activity a)
{
    super(a);
    this.c = a;
}
```

To this

```
public MyExitDialog(Activity a)
{
    super(a, R.style.CustomDialog);
    this.c = a;
}
```

**CLEANER CODE:**

Use this as your constructor.

```
public MyExitDialog(Activity a, int resID)
{
    super(a, resID);
    this.c = a;
}
```

And add resID inside the parameter like this.

```
MyExitDialog myDialog = new MyExitDialog(DrawerActivity.this, R.style.CustomDialog);
myDialog.show();
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm sorry again for giving wrong information. Notice that I didn't use `android:background`. Change it to `android:windowBackground` instead.

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/red</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: sory, but it didnt work too! its like android:background

Comment: I have done some research and it looks like the parent class of both alertDialog and Dialog does not have method that can change the scrimcolour.

Comment: But you can set the scrimColour on drawer.  @Fanous

Comment: @Fanous I have updated my code. You have to add `windowIsFloating`.  the trick is to change the backgroundColour of the dialog and when you set float to false. It will make the dialog fullscreen.

Comment: oh, finally you did it :) very thanks for your help :)

Comment: Thanks :) Very weird though. Why android didn't provide scrimColor for dialog. They only provide it for drawer. They should provide it soon in the future.

Comment: Open a new thread and ask the question there. Don't forget to post your code on what you have already done. After that you can give me the link to your new question. I will try my best to help you. :)

Answer (score 3):

To change your drawer overlay background:

```
yourDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.RED)
```

Comment: it is about drawer. what about MyExitDialog?